# Incomplete type not allowed error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opengl

I created a  class which displays labels(GameLabel) using openGL, I've gotten 2 very odd errors which i haven't been able to resolve.

error C2079: 'displayPlayer' uses undefined class 'GameLabel'
IntelliSense: incomplete type is not allowed

Here is my code;

The function in Game.cpp which calls the label class

```
void Game::draw(SDL_Window *window)
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear window

// draw player
glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glVertex3f (xpos, ypos, 0.0); // first corner
  glVertex3f (xpos+xsize, ypos, 0.0); // second corner
  glVertex3f (xpos+xsize, ypos+ysize, 0.0); // third corner
  glVertex3f (xpos, ypos+ysize, 0.0); // fourth corner
glEnd();
GameLabel displayPlayer = new GameLabel(xpos+(xsize/2.0f), ypos+ysize, "Player");
//The ablove line is the one flagging the errors.
```

Now here is the GameLabel.h.

```
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <string>
#include "Game.h"
class GameLabel
{
public:
    GameLabel(float fx, float fy, char stri);
~GameLabel(void);
void textToTexture(const char * str,  SDL_Surface* stringImage);
void draw(SDL_Surface* stringImage);
friend class Game;

protected:
SDL_Surface stringImage;
private:
GLuint texID;
GLuint height;
GLuint width;
GLfloat x;
GLfloat y;
char str;
};
```

and finally GameLabel.cpp constructor

```
GameLabel::GameLabel(float fx, float fy, char stri)
{
x = fx;
y = fy;
str = stri;

}
```

Comment: silly question.. but you did include the .h right? Are these compile errors or just intellisense errors?

Comment: I'm not this is your core problem, but `GameLabel displayPlayer = new GameLabel(...);` seems off to me.  Did you forget a `*` to declare `displayPlayer` as a pointer (e.g. `GameLabel * displayPlayer = new ...`)?

Comment: Another problem is that on your GameLabel constructor, the third argument is a char, but are trying to use a string.

Comment: The incomplete type not allowed is a intelliSense error, the other is a complie error. You're right, i did for get a pointer, I've added it now however that does not appear to have effected the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be due to circular dependancy? GameLabel includes game.h.. and game seems to depend on gamelabel as well, does Game.h include gamelabel.h?

Comment: Hi, nope there don't appear to be any circular dependancies...I've also included Game.h to the GameLabel class so it doesn't appear to be that either.

Comment: Have u included GameLabel.h to either Game.cpp or Game.h? unless necessary, prefer adding to Game.cpp, including to game.h is gonna cause circular dependancy

Comment: Including game.h into the GameLabel.cpp seemed eleminate the intellisence error, thanks! It still doesn't seem to recognising the constructor though

Comment: have you fixed the 2 problems pointed out in comments? `*displayPlayer` and `char *stri` or `std::string stri`?

Comment: Also if the friend class declaration is the only purpose of including Game.h in gamelabel.h, i suggest you remove it from there, friend declaration works without it fine.

Answer (score 2):

On all your .h files write this at the very top:

```
#ifndef YOUR_FILE_NAME_H_
#define YOUR_FILE_NAME_H_
```

and this at the very bottom:

```
#endif
```

Replace YOUR_FILE_NAME_H_ for the .h filename you are on, preferably with uppercase.

This will prevent a header file from being included multiple times.

Comment: or just `#pragma once` at the top

Comment: Okay doke, done that. It hasn't got rid of the errors though but thanks :)

Comment: @KarthikT Hey just a note, #pragma once isn't really standard, although most compilers support it

Comment: ya true found that myself, but im guessing at best makes code cleaner, and if he moves to a non supporting compiler (rare) it should not fail silently.